# Sorting a list like another list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting

I have two lists.

```
a = ["P", "h", "o", "n", "e"]
b = ["P", "n", "o", "e", "h"]
```

How do I sort `b` to be like `a`?

Comment: their lengths always same?

Comment: `sorted(b, key=lambda element: a.index(element))`? But this will be tricky if you have duplicate elements.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: or `sorted(b, key=a.index)`

Comment: @zondo oh nice one, yes. Same problem, though. Frankly `b = a[:]` is the easiest solution.

Comment: What do you mean "sort `b` to be like `a`"? If you already have `a`, make a copy of it?

Comment: What if `b` is `["P", "n", "o", "k", "l", "h"]`?  How would it be sorted?

Comment: @zondo Yup. That did that trick. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @thefourtheye I'm building a Hangman game. To display the progress the player was making I had to show him the letters he guessed in order. That's why I needed to sort the second list like the first.